# scheduleOnce with lambda in cocos2dx v3

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

`void Node::scheduleOnce(const std::function<void(float)> &callback, float delay, const std::string &key)`

what the param "key" for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

key, here, is simply a unique string that identifies the lamba being scheduled, as comparing lambda's in c++ rarely has the result you might expect.

i.e. you can pass the key to other Node methods such as `isScheduled` to see if the lambda is still scheduled, or `unschedule` etc.

Comment: I set same key in same Class obj or difference Class obj. What it happen ?

Comment: By unique I mean you (the developer) has the responsibility of choosing and managing the keys.